# Preventing ImageButtonFrom Changing its Place when Language Changes in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

How to prevent ImageButton from changing its place when language changes in RelativeLayout ?

Is there any Att. that prevent that?

**NOTE that adding *`android:supportRtl = false`* will not help because it prevents the changes in all the layouts. Howerver, I want to prevent the changes only in one layout**

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are meaning RTL Support, just adding `android:supportsRtl="false"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` will do the trick.

```
<application ...
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    ...>
        ...
</application>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to remove RTL support for a layout, just change start/end layout properties to left/right equivalents.

**FOR EXAMPLE:** If you have `paddingStart` property in a layout view, change it into `paddingRight`.

Comment: Hi @JudgedPluto...I update the question. Can you check it